# Write JSON to MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

POST request with json with id, name and surname to write the data in mysql database hosted on remote server. I am working ado.net mvc web api.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: i do not know how to start or what to search for. The database has 3 columns id, name and surname

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: but it need to be web app and i do not know who to get the data from json as request

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/97fc7a/webapi-restful-operations-in-webapi-using-ado-net-objects-a/